# C struct v union in embedded programming - why?

Tags: c, embedded

Is there anything that a union can do that a struct cannot?

I know that one might use a union to save memory space, but these days it hardly matters.

Comment: You know the basic difference between a struct and a union?

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr Yes. Only one variable at a time in a union.

Comment: With a union you can treat a single memory location as different data types, e.g. 32bit can become 32bit or 4x8bit or anything inbetween, where in a struct these data entities are stored in separate memory locations.

Comment: *"but these days it hardly matters"* the project I am currently working on: *Data Memory Usage : 3712 bytes   90.6 % Full*

Comment: @Oldfart I've been spoiled by using STM32 MCUs!

Comment: @Oldfart  c'mon, 9.4% is plenty of space to work with :)

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr But I am not yet finished! I also had to remove all the SD-card debug code, shorted my I2C and UART interrupt queues and have 512 bytes stack. (no heap)

Comment: Your question is unclear because structs and unions are very different things. This is like asking is there anything grease can do which glue cannot. The only answer is an explanation of what structs and unions are, but that's not what you're asking and wouldn't be on-topic here anyway.

Comment: "these days it hardly matters" ... and *this* is why I'm sitting here using a machine with 8GB of RAM (512 times the amount I had in my first computer!) and *still* run out of memory performing operations that really ought to be trivial...

Comment: @brhans No, my question is about use in an embedded environment

Comment: The use in an embedded environment is the same as in a non-embedded environment. They're features of the C language which make it easier and more convenient to manage and group data in particular ways. You can certainly do the same job without one or both, but it's cleaner & easier to write and maintain if you use them appropriately. My day-job is writing embedded firmware and I regularly use both structs and unions where the appropriate one is useful. I don't know if the fact that they visually appear the same is causing confusion for you, but they're completely different things.

Comment: And to address one of the points you wrote in your question "one might use a union to save memory space" - this is not what a union is for. I don't recall ever using a union to save memory space and I've been using them for 20 years.

Comment: Since a union is a sum type and a struct is a product type, your question is a lot like asking "is there anything that a ∪ can do that a ∩ cannot?".

Comment: @T.C. True - but a product is just a multiple of sums.

Comment: "To save memory space" is not the reason one would use a union.

Comment: I have used unions of structs in the past; very useful on occasion.

Comment: "but these days it hardly matters" Are we C programming or Java programming? because it sounds more like Java

Comment: @laptop2d I am currently tweaking a 50k code + 20k data bit of firmware on a 32 bit MCU with 256k flash and 64k data. Speed is what is in short supply, not space

Comment: The only use of unions is so-called "type punning". They are most commonly used for serialization/de-serialization of data. To use unions to store unrelated data in the same memory area is something else and considered bad practice and banned by for example MISRA-C.

Answer (score 7):

The use of a UNION permits formatting a particular storage allocation to different variable types or layouts. This can be used to advantage in a number of ways. Here are a couple of examples.

1. You have a UNION that defines the various record layouts for packets of data that arrive from a communication channel.
2. You can use the UNION to efficiently unpack data from one variable type to another such as overlaying a "uint_32" with a "uint_8[4]" to unpack bytes from a dword.

Comment: Note that type punning using a union is non standard (IIRC, technically implementation defined) but widely supported as it is such a common idiom.

Comment: The way the standard wants you to type pun is to use memcpy.

Comment: It all depends what you are trying to do. If you are trying to make portable code that is reusable across tool sets and architectures then by all means follow the standards recommendations. On the other hand if you are trying to solve a problem in the most efficient way possible, both code size and execution time, then you look to what your tools and architecture can do for you to achieve needed results.

Comment: Interestingly modern compilers often grok memcpy deeply enough to be able to completely remove the call when it is being used to avoid type punning. The things really are getting disturbingly smart (Compilers equate to data compressors equate to AI in some sense).

Answer (score 5):

The difference between a Union and a struct already has been explained.

If you know there is only one value (which can have different types) than use a union. optionally you need another variable that keeps track what type the union is. Like:

```
union 
{
   uint8_t value_8;
   uint16_t value_16;
   uint32_t value_32;
};

enum EUnionType { VALUE_8, VALUE_16, VALUE_36 } _unionType;
```

The enum _unionType can be set to VALUE_8/16/32 to denote what type the union has.

About memory: Memory IS important, especially for some microcontrollers which have less memory (e.g. Arduino Uno with 2 KB). And if you have 400 of these unions (in an array) it is a difference:

- Struct: 4 + 2 + 1 bytes = 7 bytes, per element. Times 400 = 2,800 bytes -> Does not fit in memory.
- Union : 4 bytes * 400 = 1,600 bytes -> Fits in memory.

Comment: Please note that using unions like this in order to create "variants" is considered bad practice and banned by for example MISRA-C. If you need to save memory, use raw `uint8_t[]` arrays instead. That way you also exclude the potential for struct/union padding bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Within a union, every element is stored at the same memory location, e.g.

```
union{
  uint32_t a;
  uint8_t b[4];
}
```

If you modify b[], you also modify a, because they're using the same physical adress. It's convenient, if you have use data as different types.

Within structures, each element is places one after the other with different adresses.

Answer (score 3):

As already described, Union is a kind of predefined typecast, where all elements will share the same memory space, so is pretty handy to do data serialization and deserialization (as long both systems share the same endianness)

As example:

---

For accessing the second byte of a 32bit int using union:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    union{
      uint32_t a;
      uint8_t b[4];
    } test;
    test.a = 0xAABBCCDD;
    printf("Hello, world! %x\n", test.a);
    printf("Hello, world! %x\n", test.b[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

---

The exactly same thing could be done with a type cast:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t test = 0xAABBCCDD;
    printf("Hello, world! %x\n", test);
    printf("Hello, world! %x\n", ((uint8_t*)&test)[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

---

The difference is that the union already "packed" the access for you, allowing you to access the same data in a "clearer" way.